# jq - concatenate passed arguments with strings

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm able to use arguments if they are not surrounded by quotes:

```
var=$(jq -n --arg hostname "my-hostname" '{
  Name: $hostname
}
)

echo $var
```

Result:

```
{
  Name: "my-hostname"
}
```

But I want to concatenate the variable with an existing string, it ignores the value:

```
var=$(jq -n --arg hostname "my-hostname" '{
  Name: "prefix-value-$hostname"
}
)

echo $var
```

Result:

```
{
  Name: "prefix-value-"
}
```

Expected:

```
{
  Name: "prefix-value-my-hostname"
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace

```
"prefix-value-$hostname"
```

with

```
"prefix-value-\( $hostname )"
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/xt47t7a504)

or

```
"prefix-value-" + $hostname
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/9k6fAk-7Xp)

---

Note that since host names can't contain line feeds, `-n` and `--arg` could be replaced with `-R` and stdin.

```sh
echo my-hostname | jq -R '{ Name: "prefix-value-\(.)" }'
```

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/JvYxfl71MU)